# What is usercustomize

Tags: python

I have seen many mentions of usercustomize throughout the docs. What is it exactly?

I am on Ubuntu 12.0, Python 3.3, using the IDLE interpreter.

Adding a `'usercustomize.py'` file to `/usr/lib/python3.3` with the following code in it:

```
import math
```

I started the IDLE interpreter. Without importing math, I typed `math.sqrt(`

Typing Ctrl + \ to start the auto complete suggestion, I get a prompt like `sqrt(x)`. This suggests that math in fact has been imported. But actually calling the function raises `NameError`.

What exactly *is* going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`site` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) for full documentation on what `usercustomize` is meant to do.

Note that `usercustomize` is only imported if [`site.ENABLE_USER_SITE`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.ENABLE_USER_SITE) is enabled:

> After this, an attempt is made to import a module named `usercustomize`, which can perform arbitrary user-specific customizations, if `ENABLE_USER_SITE` is true. This file is intended to be created in the user site-packages directory (see below), which is part of `sys.path` unless disabled by `-s`. An `ImportError` will be silently ignored.

Importing `math` into `usercustomize` will **not** make it available in IDLE; you are not making it a built-in that way. You could add it to the [`builtins` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), but I'd advice against that.

`usercustomize` is not meant to set up a default IDLE environment, it is meant to add extra entries to the `sys.path` module search path and other general Python runtime environment changes.

Comment: I wasn't trying to add math as a builtin though. I don't see any practical reason, I was just trying to figure out what usercustomize can do. :)